# which freebase api(s) returns details for machine ids? (mid)

Tags: freebase

I am attempting to develop a Freebase Explorer application. one part of the application allows a user to drill down through freebase Domains, then types then type instances, then finally using the freebase Topic API i display the selected Type Instance. however many of the type instances lists do have "null" for the name and machine ids for the id.
what combination of freebase api calls can i employ to return something of value/interest (man readable) using a freebase mid?
where should i look in the freebase site/wiki to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A machine ID (MID) can be used anywhere any other ID is used in Freebase.  There's no requirement that an object have a name.  "Something of value/interest" will depend a lot on the context, but the types and property values of an object help show how it's connected to the rest of the graph.

You might also look at the existing [Freebase Schema Explorer app](http://schemas.freebaseapps.com/) for ideas and inspiration.

Comment: Tom thanks for your time spent in responding, what i do not understand is why doesn't the TOPIC API return any Description text for mids?

Comment: Can you provide an example?  If the topic has a description and the topic isn't returning it when given the MID, but does when given other types of IDs, I'd characterize that as a bug which should be reported to Google.  The intention is for all forms of IDs to be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Tom's explanation regarding machine ids is spot on, here is some additional information:

Domains and types are schema objects and it's preferable that you use human readable ids for these. Items "of interest" are usually topics, and those are all objects that are typed with /common/topic.

You can use MQL to get a list of types and domains, and then as you say use the Topic API - which will also be available in the new APIs - to get all the data for a given topic.